# Magento 2 : How to update 'Update cart' Button`s Template?

Tags: checkout, layout, cart, xml, magento2.3

I have develop **custom module** that can update **add to cart** and update cart button but I can`t update Update cart button

I have update Add to Cart button using `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
      <action method="setTemplate">
          <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Customproduct::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
      </action>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Customproduct::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
```

I have try to update update cart button using 'checkout_cart_configure.xml'

I want to Over write template

> \vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\configure\updatecart.phtml

So I have create

> app\code\Vendor\Customproduct\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_configure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Magento_Checkout::js/view/configure/product-customer-data.js"/>
    </head>
    <update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_cart_configure_head_components" template="Magento_Checkout::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Configure" name="checkout.cart.item.configure.block"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Customproduct::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Customproduct::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Customproduct\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\configure\updatecart.phtml

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Update Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="box-tocart update">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
            <div class="field qty">
                <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="number"
                           name="qty"
                           id="qty"
                           value=""
                           title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                           class="input-text qty"
                           data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit"
                        title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?>"
                        class="action primary tocart"
                        id="product-updatecart-button">
                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $buttonTitle ?></span>
                </button>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "#product_addtocart_form": {
                "validation": {},
                "addToCart": {
                    "cartButtonId": "#product-updatecart-button",
                    "cartForm": "#product_addtocart_form"
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script>alert('i am here');</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

But There is no changes

So If You have any solution then Please help

Comment: what type of updation you want to make in update cart button ??

Comment: I want to overwrite tamplate \vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\configure\updatecart.phtml

Comment: can you please check my answer and let me know if issue resolved

Comment: can you include which button are you trying to update? I mean a screenshot is much better.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/buD8f.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For customization on the Update cart button.Please follow this link it is worked great:

[How to override the checkout_cart_configure.xml template file into custom module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/267765/how-to-override-the-checkout-cart-configure-xml-template-file-into-custom-module)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments if you only want to override

```
\vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\configure\updatecart.phtml
```

This can be done by creating same file in your theme at:

/app/design/frontend/Namespace/Theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml

Try this:

As you did for addtocart using catalog_product_view can you try using  "checkout_cart_configure" originally at /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_configure.xml

Create a new in your module and change argument same as you did for add to cart, see original vendor for reference.

Let me know if any issue

Comment: here i am develop only Extension not a theme so provide solution for this if u have

Comment: please check my updated answer if it works for you

Comment: i have test it but there is no changes you can see my update on this question

Comment: do all setup upgrade, di compile, cache flush

Comment: i have run all commands

Comment: when i have change in original file of mageto vendor`s phtml then it work and i have also check xml by removing header of page, it works proper but phtml is not rendering in page

Comment: possible some issue in module sequence due to which core one is called and not yours

Comment: Can u Explain how default flow of checkout_cart_configure.xml
what is <update handle="catalog_product_view"/> in this file

Answer (score 0):

As per the image attached, I can confirm that your code is right.
However, you will not be able to see or notice the changes unless you try to change the characters in this line (in your updatecart.phtml):

```
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Update Cart'); ?>
```

or by inspecting it in your browser. And you will find the classes present in your **`.phtml`** file.
From there, you will be able to see that your override is working.