# How to override the checkout_cart_configure.xml template file into custom module

Tags: cart, magento2.3

I want to change button text into the update cart.I have add into the my custom code but overriding is not working.please refer the my following code

> vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_configure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <link src="Magento_Checkout::js/view/configure/product-customer-data.js"/>
</head>
<update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="checkout_cart_configure_head_components" template="Magento_Checkout::js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Configure" name="checkout.cart.item.configure.block"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Into my custom module layout file

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_configure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>        
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Cirklestudio_Customproduct::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Cirklestudio_Customproduct::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\configure\updatecart.phtml

```
<?php

echo "worked";
```

Please refer following screenshot:
[image]

Please provide me the solution how to override them
Thanks

Comment: what do you want to do, change the text of the button?

Comment: I want to add a custom button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Long time I am Get the Answer

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_configure.xml

```
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Zarathemes_Customproduct::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Zarathemes_Customproduct::cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\configure\updatecart.phtml

```
echo "worked";
die;
```

After Please run the following commands:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean